# Q# versus LIQUi|>

Tags: q#

Is Q# meant to be a LIQUiD replacement? It's unclear from the website that's this is true, but I haven't heard anything about LIQUiD since the announcement of Q#. There seems to be a large set of tools in LIQUiD that are not available in Q#, so are these meant to be linked together via .NET? In particular, I am interested in the circuit class and optimizations for QECC in LIQUiD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LiQUi|> (which I'll write Liquid from now on :-)) and Q# have different goals. Liquid is an F#-based platform for simulating quantum circuits. It provides a lot of handy tools and features, like the QECC and noise modelling components you mention. It provides full access to (and manipulation of, if desired) the quantum state, so you can simulate things with Liquid that you could never do on a real quantum system. Finally, Liquid includes some highly-optimized capabilities for simulating Hamiltonian simulations that do a bunch of linear algebra tricks that are not available on a real quantum system.

Q# is a high-level language for coding quantum algorithms. Its goal is to let you easily code large quantum applications that would eventually be run on a large quantum system (hundreds of logical, error-corrected qubits). It does support simulation, but as a debugging aid. Put another way, Q# isn't primarily a language for programming quantum simulations, even though that's the way it's used today because of the low availability of large-scale quantum systems.

Liquid is still alive. If your focus is on simulation, Liquid is a great choice: you can get direct access to the innards of the simulator, but still code at a high level.

Q# is active and growing. While the focus is on actual execution, the Quantum Development Kit already includes both a full state vector simulator and a resource-estimating simulator (the trace simulator). I wouldn't be too surprised if more debugging features, including simulation, are on the way; for instance, the June release added the `DumpMachine` and `DumpRegister` operations to allow debugging access to the full state vector.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I was under the same impression as you say, but I've been told differently by several researchers in the field in the past couple of months.